# database schema has changed

Tags: c#, sqlite

I keep getting this error `database schema has changed near "1": syntax error`.

I am not changing my schema in the code.
This is the code where I make the schema.
wish to try each answer in order that you posted it.
This code is used to transfer a database to another database program.
So it has to be compatible with more then one database program.

```
public DataTable GetSchemaTable(string schema, string nameTable)
    {
        switch (m_dbType)
        {
            case dbTypeEnum.Sqlite:
                //Make the schema of the source table
                MakeConnectionString();
                string fullTableName = schema.Length > 0
                    ? string.Format("[{0}].[{1}]", schema, nameTable)
                    : string.Format("[{0}]", nameTable);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullTableName))
                {
                    string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} LIMIT 1", fullTableName);
                    DataTable dtSchemaSource;
                    try
                    {
                        using (IDataReader rdr = ReadOnlyForwardOnly(sql))
                        {
                            dtSchemaSource = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        CloseConnection();
                    }
                    if (dtSchemaSource == null)
                    {
                        throw new RadGeneralException("rdr.GetSchemaTable() returns null with sql = " + sql);
                    }

                    return dtSchemaSource;
                }
                break;

            default:
                //Make the schema of the source table
                MakeConnectionString();
                string fullTableName = schema.Length > 0
                    ? string.Format("[{0}].[{1}]", schema, nameTable)
                    : string.Format("[{0}]", nameTable);
                string sql = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {0}", fullTableName);
                DataTable dtSchemaSource;
                try
                {
                    using (IDataReader rdr = ReadOnlyForwardOnly(sql))
                    {
                        dtSchemaSource = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseConnection();
                }
                if (dtSchemaSource == null)
                {
                    throw new RadGeneralException("rdr.GetSchemaTable() returns null with sql = " + sql);
                }
                return dtSchemaSource;

        }
    }
```

This is the part where the sqlite schema has changed arror occurs.

```
StringBuilder sbColList = new StringBuilder();
        nCol = 0;
        identityColInBothTables = false;
        //Make the schema of the source table
        DataTable dtSchemaSource = objDbSource.GetSchemaTable(SchemaSource, Name);
        //Make the schema of the target table
        DataTable dtSchemaTarget = objDbTarget.GetSchemaTable(SchemaTarget, Name);
```

Comment: If you still have Problems with the `LIMIT` solutions, then you should post the `ReadOnlyForwardOnly` and `GetSchemaTable` code as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that instead of `SELECT TOP 1 *` you need to be using `SELECT * FROM .... LIMIT 1`

Comment: +  Thrown: "Incorrect syntax near '1'." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) Exception Message = "Incorrect syntax near '1'.", Exception Type = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException", Exception WinRT Data = null 

still get the error

Comment: long story short this helped me. still have new errors coming up :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check nameTable is null or empty

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullTableName))
 string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} LIMIT 1", fullTableName);
```

**for SQLLITE**

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name LIMIT 1;
```

**for SQL**

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table_Name;
```

Comment: `TOP 1` is invalid syntax in sqlite

Comment: @Fred  Thanks... Updated

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE ORDER BY ROWID ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: can you check the string query when you are calling ExecuteReader()